# Recursive lisp-function to solve N-Queen

Tags: recursion, common-lisp, n-queens

UPDATED: The code should compile now without errors or warnings. Sorry about the previous one. The problem I have now is that when a run (or with any other integer)

```
(NxNqueen-solver 10)
```

The function **getqueencol** will return nil because there are no queens on the board in the first place, hence there will be a (= number nil) in the **queen-can-be-placed-here** because tcol will be nil. I think this will happen everytime there is no queen in the row passed as argument to the **queen-can-be-placed-here** function.

Please share some advice on how to fix this problem. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code

```
(defvar *board* (make-array '(10 10) :initial-element nil)) 


(defun getqueencol (row n)
"Traverses through the columns of a certain row
 and returns the column index of the queen."
  (loop for i below n
        do (if (aref *board* row i)
               (return-from getqueencol i))))

(defun print-board (n)
"Prints out the solution, e.g. (1 4 2 5 3),
 where 1 denotes that there is a queen at the first 
 column of the first row, and so on."
  (let ((solutionlist (make-list n)))
    (loop for row below n
          do (loop for col below n
                   do (when (aref *board* row col)
                        (setf (nth row solutionlist) col))))
    (print solutionlist)))


(defun queen-can-be-placed-here (row col n)
"Returns t if (row,col) is a possible place to put queen, otherwise nil."
  (loop for i below n
       do (let ((tcol (getqueencol i n)))
            (if (or (= col tcol) (= (abs (- row i)) (abs (- col tcol))))
                (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here nil)))))



(defun backtracking (row n)
"Solves the NxN-queen problem with backtracking"
  (if (< row n)
      (loop for i below n
          do (when (queen-can-be-placed-here row i n)
                  (setf (aref *board* row i) 't)
                  (return-from backtracking (backtracking (+ row 1) n))
                  (setf (aref *board* row i) 'nil))
    (print-board n))))

(defun NxNqueen-solver (k)
"Main program for the function call to the recursive solving of the problem"
  (setf *board* (make-array '(k k) :initial-element nil))
  (backtracking 0 k))
```

Comment: You have several errors in your code, so, how can you say that the functions compile? For instance you have `(return-from getmarkedcol)` inside `getqueencol`; you do a `(setq solutionlist ...)` without having defined `solutionlist`, there is a malformed `let` in `(let (tcol (getqueencol i))`, etc... Moreover, you should not use a `defvar` inside a function.

Comment: @Renzo Thank you. Please have a look at my answer below. Code is compiling but getting "variable unbound"

Comment: Btw., it is better style to pass the board to the functions and to not use a global variable for it.

Comment: Think about these questions: 1. What is the difference between _e.g._ `'(pi pi)` _aka._ `(quote pi pi)`, and `(list pi pi)`?  2. How many queens do you have to consider when placing the i-th queen?  3. What makes `queen-can-be-placed-here` return anything but nil?  4. What is the purpose of calling `return-from` in `backtracking`?   Hopefully, you will then get the program to work, and may then benefit from submitting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I now understand the difference between `'(pi pi)` and `(list pi pi)`. Question 3: I have added a `(return-from queen-can-be-placed-here t)` outside the loop so that it can return TRUE as well. Question 4: I have removed the `return-from` statement in `backtracking`. I don't think there is a purpose terminating the code at that step. Question 2: Because I am using backtracking it should be enough to consider the i-th - 1 queen right? But this is were I have problem. My `getqueencol` always returns `nil` when there is no queen in  a certain row... Please help me!

Comment: Then don't call `getqueencol` on rows where there is yet no queen.

Comment: @TerjeD. Could you please suggest a way to do that? I have tried loop the columns of a certain row in `queen-can-be-placed-here` and checking whether there is a queen there or not. The thing I don

Comment: @TerjeD. Dont mind the first comment. Thank you for your answer.So now I have a variable in `queen-can-be-placed-here` that knows whether a certain row has a queen or not. But what kind of check can I do to determine if it is a possible position for the queen? I can not use the one have written already in `queen-can-be-placed-here`  I presume, because it uses `tcol` which cannot be used if there's not a queen in the row. Thank you in advance

Comment: In order not to call `getqueencol`in vain: Maybe you should just loop `below row` in `queen-can-be-placed-here`.

Comment: Thank you so much @TerjeD. !!! It seems to be working now. What I don't understand though is that my program finds ALL solutions to the problem. I thought it would just find one and then print that one. Do you understand why it finds all solutions and not just settles with one? :D

Comment: You should make that a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You say that you compiled your code. That can't be the case, since then you would have see the compiler complaining about errors. You want to make sure that you really compile the code and correct the code, such that it compiles without errors and warnings.

You might want to get rid of the errors/problems in the code (see Renzo's comment) and then look at the algorithmic problem. I makes very little sense to look into an algorithmic problem, when the code contains errors.

- `SETQ` does not introduce a variable, the variable has to be defined somewhere
- `DEFVAR` makes no sense inside a function.
- Something like `(let (x (sin a)) ...)` definitely looks wrong. The syntax of `LET` requires a pair of parentheses around the bindings list.
- `RETURN-FROM` takes as first argument the name of an existing *block* to return from. The optional second argument is a return value. Get the syntax right and return from the correct block.
- in a call to `MAKE-ARRAY` specify the default value: `(make-array ... :initial-element nil)`, otherwise it's not clear what it is.
- The variable `*board*` is undefined

**Style**

- in `LOOP`:  `for i to (1- n)` is simpler `for i below n`
- you don't need to quote `NIL` and `T`.
- `(if (eq foo t) ...)` might be simpler written as `(if foo ...)`. Especially if the value of `foo` is either `NIL` or `T`.
- `(if foo (progn ...))` is simply `(when foo ...)`

---

I'm not sure what you are doing to claim that your code compiles. It does not compile.

**Every function has compiler warnings. You should check the compiler warnings and fix the problems.**

```
(defun getqueencol (row)
"Traverses through the columns of a certain row
 and returns the column index of the queen."
  (loop for i below n
        do (if (aref board row i)
               (return-from getqueencol i))))
```

The compiler complains:

```
;;;*** Warning in GETQUEENCOL: N assumed special
;;;*** Warning in GETQUEENCOL: BOARD assumed special
```

Where is `n` defined? Where is `board` coming from?

```
(defun print-board (board)
"Prints out the solution, e.g. (1 4 2 5 3),
 where 1 denotes that there is a queen at the first 
 column of the first row, and so on."
  (let (solutionlist)
    (setq solutionlist (make-list n)))
  (loop for row below n
        do (loop for col below n
               do (when (aref board row col)
                      (setf (nth row solutionlist) col))))
  (print solutionlist))
```

The `LET` makes no sense. `(let (foo) (setq foo bar) ...)` is `(let ((foo bar)) ...)`.

Why is solutionlist not defined? Look at the `LET`... it does not make sense.

Where is `n` coming from?

```
(defun queen-can-be-placed-here (row col)
"Returns t if (row,col) is a possible place to put queen, otherwise nil."
  (loop for i below n
       do (let (tcol)
            (setq tcol (getqueencol i)))
       (if (or (= col tcol) (= (abs (- row i)) (abs (- col tcol))))
          (return-from queen-can-be-placed-here nil))))
```

where is `n` coming from? The `LET` makes no sense.

```
(defun backtracking (row)
"Solves the NxN-queen problem with backtracking"
  (if (< row n)
      (loop for i below n
          do (when (queen-can-be-placed-here row i)
                  (setf (aref board row i) 't)
                  (return-from backtracking (backtracking (+ row 1)))
                  (setf (aref board row i) 'nil))
    (print-board board))))
```

Where is `n` coming from? Where is `board` defined?

```
(defun NxNqueen-solver (k)
"Main program for the function call to the recursive solving of the problem"
    (let (n board)
          (setq n k)
          (setq board (make-array '(k k) :initial-element nil)))
        (backtracking 0))
```

Why use `setq` when you have a `let`? The local variables `n` and `board` are unused.

`MAKE-ARRAY` expects a list of numbers, not a list of symbols.

I propose you use a basic Lisp introduction ([Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/index.html) - free download) and a Lisp reference ([CL Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm)).

Comment: To OP: try to find out why you don't need to quote `NIL` and `T`.

Comment: Hi Rainer. Please have a look at my answer below. I have updated the code according to your response and it is now compiling but there is a "variable unbound".

Comment: @RichardBerg: see my updates. The compiler shows lots of warnings. Fix them first...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Hi Rainer. Please see my edited topic. Code complies now without ny warnings or errors.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Do you mean wrong as if it does not compile? I have highlighted the code in my editor and tried Buffer, Definition, File > Compile, and none of them say anything about error or warning. All it says is -----Done-----, or ------Press Space to Continue----------. Am I compiling the right way? Sorry for the stupid questions and I truly appreciate your patience :)

Comment: @RichardBerg: `'(k k)` is a list of two symbols. Not what Lisp wants. The LispWorks compiler does not complain, but it just does not run...: `Bad argument to MAKE-ARRAY: (K K)`. --- I'm not giving you the direct answer, you have to find it out. I hope that's okay? ;-)

Comment: @RainerJoswig Hey Rainer and thank you for all your help. The program is finally working as it should now. What I am curious about is how I can modify `backtracking` so that the program will exit as soon as it has found and printed ONE solution only. Right now it is finding all possible solutions, I guess that is because  each time it returns from a call, there is still loops pending at different levels of recursion. Do you have any idea how to exit `backtracking` so that I have only 1 solution?